# function for including pages

Tags: php, arrays, function, include

I'm trying to make a function for including pages.

In fact For the beginning I used to work with a long code that checked for all pages:

```
if (isset($_GET]['p']) && $_GET['p']=='something') {include 'something.php'};
```

Now I work with more than 600 pages and this code is too long and I would like to simplify it.

Sometimes I do have pages that are note entitled like they are used, for example home will correspond to accueil.php etc.

So I've done an array in which I listed all exceptions:

like that:

```
$paramListepages = array(
    'corbeille' => array(
        'libelle'     => 'corbeille',
        'page'        => 'php/trash.php'
    ),   
    'nouveaumessage' => array(
        'libelle'     => 'nouveaumessage',
        'page'        => 'php/envoyer.php'
    ),
```

etc...

In this array I have about 20 pages.

Now I've tried to create a function for including pages so here is my code:

```
function getPage($var)
{
    if (isset($var)) {
        $key = array_search($var, $paramListepages);
        if ($key == false()) {
            include('php/'.$var.'.php');    
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand why the first part does not work.

I first of all check if the var does exist in the array, if not I include the page corresponding to the var.

I do still do not know how to do the second part, but for now the first one does not work.

I have no message error, even if in my ubunto I activated the displaying of all errors.

In the main page `index.php` I call the function `getPage($_GET['p'])`

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `false()` is not a function.  Change it to `if ($key == false) {`. Also, `include` is **not a function** either, it is a language construct; so no parenthesis should be used.  make it `include '/path/to/file.php';`

Comment: thanks for this part it works fine actualy, I've changed, the last trouble is how to get the correct value of the page fr'om the frst array?

Comment: `function false(){ return false; }`. And that was a joke.

Comment: @StasGrin: I just thought what would happen on SO if you would spread a function `function false(){return true;}`...

Comment: @arkascha try it out. that passed with no erors\warnig\notices. otherwise see wiki for "sarcasm" tag .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest accessing the entries in your array directly:

```
function getPage($var) {
    if (empty($var))
        // no page specified => default page
        inlude('index.php')
    elseif (array_key_exists($var,$paramListepages))
        // page found => include it!
        include (sprintf('php/%s.php', $paramListepages[$var]['page']));
    else
        // page not found => default page
        inlude ('index.php')
}
```